# How to declare the xlink namespace to validate a Docbook 5 link?

Tags: validation, namespaces, xml-namespaces, xlink, docbook-5

Might I use `xl`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<article xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" xmlns:xl="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="5.0">
    ...
</article>
```

or do I have to use `xlink`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<article xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="5.0">
    ...
</article>
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xml validation and namespaces usually set the question in the context of XML Schema (XSD) specification, but the question may be answered in Document Type Definition (DTD) specification context.

## Validating against `docbook.dtd`

If you validate against `docbook.dtd` you must use `xmlns:xlink` as answered  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152687/what-is-the-correct-xlink-namesapce-to-use-in-docbook-5), but first carefully consider why you should have to use [Document Type Declaration and namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096505/document-type-declaration-and-namespaces) because XML Schemas are the Successors of DTDs and while XSDs support namespaces DTDs don't support them.

## Validating against `docbook.xsd`

If you validate against `docbook.xsd` you may use whatever you like, but the reserved [three-letter sequence x, m, l, in any case combination](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#xmlReserved). For example the following `test.xml`, straight taken from the [DocBook V5.0 - The Transition Guide](http://docbook.org/docs/howto/#changes-linking) validates with success:

```
$ ls
docbook.xsd  test.xml  xlink.xsd  xml.xsd
$ xmllint --schema docbook.xsd test.xml 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<article xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" xmlns:xl="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="5.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    <section>
        <title>LS command</title>
        <para xml:id="ls">
            This command is a synonym for <command linkend="dir">DIR</command> command.
        </para>
        <para xml:id="dir">
            This command is a synonym for <command linkend="ls">LS</command> command.
        </para>
        <para>
            <application xl:href="http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/">Emacs</application>
        </para>
    </section>
</article>
test.xml validates
$
```